# Can't pass local var into post callback function with jquery

Tags: debugging, jquery, post

***This has been asked and answered several times, yet I keep comparing my syntax to the proper syntax as described in the answeres, and can't find what's wrong.***

```
$('.voteBtn').bind('click', function () {
    var vote = 1;
    $.post(
        "vote.php",
        { vote: vote},
        function(vote) {
            alert (vote); // BUG HERE
        }
    );
});
```

My expected result is an alert of '1', as defined at `var vote = 1;`

But the current result is an alert of a blank string.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a parameter called `vote` which is causing the problem, so inside the ajax callback `vote` variable is referring to the data returned by the ajax request, not the closure variable in the click handler

To fix the problem rename the parameter to something else like `data`

```
$('.voteBtn').bind('click', function () {
    var vote = 1;
    $.post("vote.php", {
        vote: vote,
        pollID: id
    }, function (data) {
        alert(vote); // BUG HERE
    });
});
```

Comment: I see. so 'data' contains all the parent function's variables?

Comment: @Roy no. Data is just the returned value for `vote.php` as I pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `vote` that you `alert` is the  data returned from your ajax request, not the one you defined before, try to use this instead:

```
$('.voteBtn').bind('click', function () {
    var $vote = 1;
    $.post(
        "vote.php",
        { vote: $vote},
        function(vote) {
            alert ($vote); // BUG HERE
        }
    );
});
```